# Render JavaScript to HTML in Python?

Tags: javascript, python, html, rendering, static-files

#### What

My web-app is made dynamic through Google's [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org/).

I want static versions of my pages to be generated.

#### Why

Web-scrapers like Google's execute and render the JavaScript; but don't treat the content the same way as their static equivalents.

References:

- [Does heavy JavaScript use adversely impact Googleability?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/151440) (Programmers StackExchange)
- [Making AJAX Applications Crawlable](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling) (Google Documentation for webmasters)

#### How

Not sure exactly how—which is why I'm asking—but I want to access the same source that your browser's 'inspect element' presents; rather than the source that: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> (View page source) shows.

Once I have a script which renders the page; 'spitting' out the HTML+CSS; I will place those 'generated' files on my web-server. A 'cron' job will then be scheduled to regenerate the files at regular intervals.

These static files will subsequently be served instead of the dynamic ones; when JavaScript is disabled and/or when a scraper 'visits' the site.

Comment: That's the sort of thing that having your server written in Python is not good for—if you're bent on using something like AngularJS, it's a time when running Node on the server might actually be worthwhile.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan: I am using Python to manage the interface between the controllers—exposing my data RESTfully—and my models—managing the connection between the Python and database(s). I also use Python to manage the caching and whatever other web-app relevant 'things'. Sure, I could do this in Node.js; but I'd rather do this in Python (if possible).

Comment: Well, if you're wanting to achieve the effect, you basically have two options: (a) do what the JavaScript does, in Python code, or (b) actually execute the JavaScript in the page. The first option will take effort to maintain but could be good for producing an API (depends on precisely what it all is) and the second will take some setup (e.g. running a webkit headless and fetching and serving the result when the scripts have run) and is also likely to hinder performance not inconsiderably.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one solution, however I very much doubt I'll be able to find a public PaaS cloud which can run it:

```
import spynner

if __name__=='__main__':
    url = "http://angular.github.com/angular-phonecat/step-10/app/#/phones"
    browser = spynner.Browser()
    browser.create_webview(True)
    browser.load(url, load_timeout=60)
    print browser._get_html()
    # ^ Can pipe this to a file, POST it to my server or return it as a string
    browser.close()
```

Package: [Spynner (on Github)](https://github.com/makinacorpus/spynner/)