# Finding span by class and extracting its contents

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to extract text of a particular span which is given in the snapshot. I am unable to find the span by its class attribute. I have attached The html source (snapshot) of the data to be extracted as well.
Any suggestions?

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib 
sourceUrl='https://www.pakwheels.com/forums/t/planing-a-trip-from-karachi-to-lahore-by-road-in-feb-2017/414115/2'
source=urllib.request.urlopen(sourceUrl).read()
soup=bs.BeautifulSoup(source, 'html.parser')

count=soup.find('span',{'class':'number'})
print(len(count))
```

See the image:

[image: See the image]

Answer (score 1):

If you disable JavaScript in your browser you can easily see that span element that you want are disappearing.
In order to get that element one of the possible solutions can be using [Selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) browser.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.pakwheels.com/forums/t/planing-a-trip-from-karachi-to-lahore-by-road-in-feb-2017/414115/2')
span = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//li[3]/span')
print(span.text)
driver.close()
```

Output:
[image]

Another solution - find desired value deep down in web page source(in Chrome browser press Ctrl+U) and extract span value using a regular expression.

```
import re
import requests
r = requests.get(
    'https://www.pakwheels.com/forums/t/planing-a-trip-from-karachi-to-lahore-by-road-in-feb-2017/414115/2')
span = re.search('\"posts_count\":(\d+)', r.text)
print(span.group(1))
```

Output:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If You know how to use **CSS SELECTORS** you can use :

```
mySpan = soup.select("span.number")
```

It will return List of all nodes which are valid for this selector. 
So `mySpan[0]` could contain what You need. And then use one of the methods like  for example `get_text()` to get what You need.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to decode response

```
source=urllib.request.urlopen(sourceUrl).read().decode()
```

Maybe your issue will disappears after this fix

Comment: @ZeeshanUlHaq maybe your content is generated via JavaScript?
So in response you can't see it (because js is not rendered)

Comment: Yes you are right. The content is generated via JavaScript. How can i get the HTML content?

Comment: You can read this post)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14079416/render-javascript-to-html-in-python

Comment: One more question, what do you mean by "content is generated via JavaScript?". Does it have something to do with my code or is it because of the website that i am trying to parse...?
I am very confused

Comment: I am trying to scrape the text and number of replies from the following link, could you please guide me. I have been trying for quite long.
https://www.pakwheels.com/forums/t/karachi-to-khunjerab-by-road-honda-city-mt-1-3-2016/496874